# Creating a variable n times according to user input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a js program that calculates matrices, however, I can't figure out how create an array n times according to user input. For example when the program asks the user how many rows they have, I want the program to create n number of arrays that I can push the values in that row too.

Comment: Hey. What have you tried ? Did you have a look at Javascript doc about Array and everything ? May help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: Please show us your sample and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider you want a 2D matrix. There are 2 axis : X & Y. You need to build an array of arrays : the global array that contains the other will acts as columns (or rows) meanwhile the arrays stored in the global ones will be the rows (or acts, depends of what you've chosen at the first step).

An array can be instanciated this way in Javascript :

```
var matrix = [];
```

Then, we'll admit that you've asked the user for x rows and y cols. You can then build your matrix :

```
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    matrix[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < y; j++) {
         matrix[i][j] = "";
    }
}
```

For i between 0 and X, this little code will add a ligne to your matrix, plus adding j columns. Notice that i didn't set any value in your matrix but you can give it whatever value you want.

This way, the final matrix will be something that looks like :

```
[][][][][]
[][][][][]
[][][][][]
```

for a 5*3 sized matrix

Comment: i thought of making an array of arrays but wasn't sure how to go about doing that, thank you!!!!